# python or js equivalent of ruby's ServiceManager

Tags: python, ruby, node.js

Does anybody know if there is any equivalent of https://github.com/leadtune/service_manager for python or node?

i need to start executables in the background when i start my tests and the automatically quit them all when the tests end.

Comment: Please read "[ask]". It's off-topic to ask us to recommend code or libraries.

Answer (score 0):

not sure for which environment you are searching...

when it's about node.js you should look at pm2

Answer (score 0):

I think for python you can find... well... [ServiceManager](https://github.com/hmrc/service-manager)

Comment: have you used it?  I am having trouble making sense of the documentation.

Comment: No I did not, but I noticed that this project has wiki with [Real Word Usage examples](https://github.com/hmrc/service-manager/wiki/Real-World-Usage). I hope it will help.